# Relabeling two 20-sided dice without changing their total

Tags: combinatorics, probability, dice

Usually, 20-sided dice are labeled with the numbers 1 to 20. When you roll two of these, their sum is a random number between 2 and 40. The total 21 is most likely to occur, while 2 and 40 are the least. The probabilities vary linearly in between, as shown below.

> Is there **different** way to label two 20-sided dice with **positive integers**, so that their sum is still a random number between 2 and 40 with these **same** probabilities?

Without the positive integer constraint, there would be trivial solutions like [0, ... ,19] and [1, ... ,21], or [0.5, ... ,19.5] and [1.5, ... ,20.5].

This is a variant of a [more famous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18426/unusual-dice-usual-results), which asks the same question for six-sided dice.

[image]

Comment: How about an equal probability for every sum, or a bell curve distribution?

Comment: @Darcinon Equal probability between 2 and 40 is impossible, since the $20^2$ possible die roll pairs can't be split event among the 39 numbers 2...40. But you can do 1...40 with equal probability.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

*Is there a different way to label two 20-sided dice with positive integers, so that their sum is still a random number between 2 and 40 with these same probabilities?*

Answer:

> Yes.

Details:

> In fact, there are **seven** (if I counted correctly) different ways of achieving this.

More details:

> **Solution 1** 
>  Die 1: 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8 
>  Die 2: 1,5,6,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,27,28,32 
>  
>  **Solution 2** 
>  Die 1: 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11 
>  Die 2: 1,3,5,7,9,11,11,13,13,15,15,17,17,19,19,21,23,25,27,29 
>  
>  **Solution 3** 
>  Die 1: 1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,12 
>  Die 2: 1,2,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,24,27,28 
>  
>  **Solution 4** 
>  Die 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,12,13,14,15 
>  Die 2: 1,2,3,4,5,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,21,22,23,24,25 
>  
>  **Solution 5** 
>  Die 1: 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16 
>  Die 2: 1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,24 
>  
>  **Solution 6** 
>  Die 1: 1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,11,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,17 
>  Die 2: 1,2,5,6,6,7,9,10,10,11,13,14,14,15,17,18,18,19,22,23 
>  
>  **Solution 7** 
>  Die 1: 1,2,2,3,5,6,6,7,9,10,10,11,13,14,14,15,17,18,18,19 
>  Die 2: 1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9,11,11,13,13,15,15,17,17,19,19,21 
>  
>  That's it (I think)!

How I solved it, and how you can check that the solutions are correct:

> Many years ago I read a very nice math textbook called *Analytic Number Theory* by D. J. Newman. Chapter 1 of that book has a section titled **Crazy Dice** in which the same riddle linked to by the OP that deals with the case of 6-sided dice is solved using generating functions. Essentially one converts the problem to a problem of polynomial algebra. For example, the solution "die1=(1,2,2,3,3,4), die2=(1,3,4,5,6,8)" to the original crazy dice problem reduces to checking the polynomial identity
>  $$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^2 = (x+2x^2+2x^3+x^4)(x+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^8),$$
>  
> since when expanding out these products, the coefficients of powers of $x$ on the left-hand side correspond precisely to the probabilities (after dividing by 36) to get the numbers $2,3,...,12$ when rolling normal dice, and on the right-hand side this would be the same thing with the crazy dice.
>  
>  So, to solve our new problem with the $20$-sided dice we need to find corresponding identities involving a "nonstandard" factorization of the polynomial
>  
>  $$ g(x)^2 = (1+x+x^2+...+x^{19})^2$$
>  
>  into a product of two distinct polynomials whose coefficients are nonnegative and add up to $20$. I managed to do this by factorizing the polynomial $g(x)$ in Mathematica (it factors into 5 irreducible factors: $x+1$, $x^2+1$, $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$, $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, $x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1$) and then writing a small program to systematically look at all possible products of these 5 factors with powers $0,1,2$. There are a total of $3^5=243$ possibilities, so my laptop did this easily in a few seconds.

Comment: I have to say, this is an impressively clever solution which readily generalizes to any number and type of dice.

Comment: The irreducible factors of $(1+x+\ldots+x^{19})$ are exactly the cyclotomic polynomials $\phi_n$ as $n$ ranges over the divisors of $20$ (except for $n=1$).

Comment: And taking the sum of their coefficients is equivalent to evaluating them at $1$, which means you can use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/value-of-cyclotomic-polynomial-evaluated-at-1) result to further systematize things...

Comment: This transformation -- from distinct events with values to polynomial, and turning addition into multiplication -- is great for certain kinds of modelling.  It is analogous to the Fourier transform trick in more than one way.  I have lots of fun with it, and computers love it.

Answer (score 8):

A solution that fits a generalized pattern:

> [ 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 11 ]
>  
>  x [ 1 3 5 7 9 11 11 13 13 15 15 17 17 19 19 21 23 25 27 29 ]

Began by looking at what would be equivalent puzzles
for pairs of 2-sided, 4-sided, 6-sided and 8-sided dice,
along with the assumption that the intervals between their sides' numbers
would be symmetric because the resulting distribution is symmetric.

> The intervals' symmetry could be either like ABBA and CDDC,
>  as turned out to be the case, or like ABCD and DCBA, where the
>  intervals of one die reverse the intervals of the other die.
>  
>  2 sides (essentially a pair of coins with no alternative
>           to the standard spot pattern):   [1 2] x [1 2]
>  
>  4 sides (easy):   [1 2 2 3] x [1 3 3 5]
>  
>  6 sides (the famous case):   [1 2 2 3 3 4] x [1 3 4 5 6 8]
>  
>  8 sides (not too tough, based on those above):
>                               [1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5] x [1 3 5 5 7 7 9 11]

20 sides was straightforward after 8 sides refined
the pattern suggested by 2, 4 and 6 sides.

**Addendum.**
 
In the terms of
[another solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/25889/18129),
this solution neatly breaks down to
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
A = [1,2] & B=[1,11]\\
C=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] & D=[0,2,4,6,8,10.12,14,16,18]
\end{array}
$$
which clearly shows what underlies the straightforward
even-sided-dice pattern better than how I understood it.

Answer (score 6):

Let A and B be 4-sided dice with the below labels, and similarly for the [5-sided dice](http://www.shapeways.com/product/JF6RYWM66/d5-jack-blank?li=shop-results&optionId=40685693) C and D:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
A = [1,2,3,4] & B=[1,6,11,16]\\
C=[0,1,2,3,4] & D=[0,4,8,12,16]
\end{array}
$$
Notice that adding the rolls of A and D produces a random number between 1 and 20, so that A and D together simulate a d20, or A + D = d20. Similarly, B + C = d20, so
$$
\text{d20 }+\text{d20}=(A+D) + (B+C)
$$
To get a different labeling, let's shuffle these factors around:
$$
\text{d20 }+\text{d20}=(A+C) + (B+D)
$$
Rolling B and D together produces a random number in the list
$$
E=[1,6,11,16,5,10,15,20,9,14,19,24,13,18,23,28,17,22,27,32]
$$
so B + D is equal to a 20-sided die E with these labels. Similarly, A + C is equal to the 20-sided die F featuring the labels
$$
F=[1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8]
$$
This shows that d20 + d20 = E + F, so E and F are labelings that work.

---

This same method shows that there exist pairs of alternative $n$-sided dice which simulate regular $n$-sided dice, as long as $n$ is composite. The problem is impossible when $n$ is prime, which can be shown using abstract algebra by representing dice as polynomials.

Comment: Looks like my [1 ... 11] x [1 ... 29] solution neatly breaks down in your system to A = [1 2], B = [1 11], C = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] and D = [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18], which clearly shows what underlies the straightforward even-sided-dice pattern better than how I understood it. No wonder you wanted to share this puzzle and your solution.